# How to bring the button in the end in html and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button in the main navigation. In mobile view it is coming along Customers link. I want to show it below Pricing link.

How I need it:

[image: How i need like this]

```css
.nav-btn button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: AktivGrotesk-Light;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 apri-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Platform</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apps</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="d-flex nav-btn">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Request demo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run your code, I display it the way you want. What is the problem?

Comment: it is not displaying below the pricing link. 
Request a Demo should come below the Pricing link

Comment: Please see the screenshots that i have attached

Comment: I posted it as an answer, it looks like what you want.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and include CDN links in the snippet demo.

Answer (score 0):

Run this snippet and see the result.

```css
.nav-btn button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: AktivGrotesk-Light;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 apri-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"
                  >Platform</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apps</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customers</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex nav-btn">
              <button class="btn" type="submit">Request demo</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: check this and let me know if it is coming down as i need or as in your answer?

Comment: https://intellectsofts.com/demo/rex/

Comment: When I looked at the site, I saw that it did not work as you wanted. It's probably affected by some other code in your .css file.

Answer (score 0):

> Add another `div` element below the first `div` and add `justify-content-end` class aligns its child elements to the right end of the container. This will move the `ul` and `form` elements to the left side of the navbar, and the `button` to the right side.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 apri-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Platform</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apps</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customers</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="d-flex nav-btn">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Request demo</button>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: After applying your code Sudhakaran, it is coming now in front of Platform Link, the very first link in my nav

Answer (score 0):

While I was checking the website link you posted it got banned, but from what I saw and checked in that litle time the issue is simple and you can tackle it by adding 1 line into your CSS, and from what I remember there is a .navbar class wrapping both UL and Button with a property of flex. So add this line to you css

```
.navbar{
   flex-direction:column;
 }
```

In you CSS file there is already some styling used for this class just add this line there or in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you arranged your HTML elements and Bootstrap CCS class used. You need to put the lists and the button form into a new div and pass row and col classes in Bootstrap media queries to them.

The code below should resolve this for both mobile and desktop. Let me know if there is more I can do to help.

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar collapse show row" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 apri-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Platform
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apps
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customers
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form class="d-flex nav-btn align-item-center">
      <button class="btn" type="submit" fdprocessedid="jfkb08">Request demo
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```